# Azure Active Directory Domain Services: The operation failed because resource is in the: 'Failed' state

Tags: azure, powershell

When I run this cmdlet using a powershell script,

```
New-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/will-vnet-rg/providers/Microsoft.AAD/DomainServices/xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com" -Location eastus2 -Properties @{"DomainName"="xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com"; "SubnetId"="/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/will-vnet-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/will-vnet/subnets/will-core-subnet"} -ApiVersion 2017-06-01 -Force -Verbose
```

I get this error,

```
New-AzResource : The operation failed because resource is in the: 'Failed' state. Please check the logs for more details.
At C:\tf\advantage\dev\deploy\scripts\Azure-Functions.ps1:89 char:5
+     New-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$subscription/resource ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResource], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceCmdlet
```

The resources it depends on exist, earlier in my script I create them. I am able to create the Domain Service manually through the Azure Portal, however, using the powershell cmdlet to create it does not work.

In the portal, the resource says "The managed domain is in a failed state. Contact support with your Azure AD tenant ID and the domain name of the managed domain."

[Failed Domain in the portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx9r8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are also experiencing this issue, I have figured out a workaroud. I am not sure what is wrong with the New-AzResource cmdlet that I wrote, but I ended up creating the domain service manually in the portal, and then downloading the JSON template. I tried converting it to BICEP using the decompiler, but for whatever reason, it wouldn't take it. So to fix, I manually wrote a BICEP file to create the Domain Service.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $vnetResourceGroup -TemplateFile "C:\dev\pub\Bicep Files\domain.bicep" -shortName $shortName -managedDomainName $managedDomainName -location $location -subnetAddressPrefix "$($coreSubnet.AddressPrefix)"
```

Use [this link](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/blob/main/docs/examples/101/aad-domainservices/main.bicep) if you need help to write a BICEP file for a domain service.

Answer (score 0):

To create the Azure Active Directory Domain Service with powershell, you could use the built-in powershell command [`New-AzADDomainService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.addomainservices/new-azaddomainservice?view=azps-5.9.0) directly, also, you need to create some required Azure AD resources firstly.

**Sample:**

```
# Change the following values to match your deployment.
$AaddsAdminUserUpn = "admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$ResourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup"
$VnetName = "myVnet"
$AzureLocation = "westus"
$AzureSubscriptionId = "YOUR_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
$ManagedDomainName = "aaddscontoso.com"

# Connect to your Azure AD directory.
Connect-AzureAD

# Login to your Azure subscription.
Connect-AzAccount

# Create the service principal for Azure AD Domain Services.
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId "2565bd9d-da50-47d4-8b85-4c97f669dc36"

# First, retrieve the object ID of the 'AAD DC Administrators' group.
$GroupObjectId = Get-AzureADGroup `
  -Filter "DisplayName eq 'AAD DC Administrators'" | `
  Select-Object ObjectId

# Create the delegated administration group for Azure AD Domain Services if it doesn't already exist.
if (!$GroupObjectId) {
  $GroupObjectId = New-AzureADGroup -DisplayName "AAD DC Administrators" `
    -Description "Delegated group to administer Azure AD Domain Services" `
    -SecurityEnabled $true `
    -MailEnabled $false `
    -MailNickName "AADDCAdministrators"
  }
else {
  Write-Output "Admin group already exists."
}

# Now, retrieve the object ID of the user you'd like to add to the group.
$UserObjectId = Get-AzureADUser `
  -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$AaddsAdminUserUpn'" | `
  Select-Object ObjectId

# Add the user to the 'AAD DC Administrators' group.
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $GroupObjectId.ObjectId -RefObjectId $UserObjectId.ObjectId

# Register the resource provider for Azure AD Domain Services with Resource Manager.
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.AAD

# Create the resource group.
New-AzResourceGroup `
  -Name $ResourceGroupName `
  -Location $AzureLocation

# Create the dedicated subnet for AAD Domain Services.
$SubnetName = "DomainServices"
$AaddsSubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
  -Name DomainServices `
  -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/24

$WorkloadSubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
  -Name Workloads `
  -AddressPrefix 10.0.1.0/24

# Create the virtual network in which you will enable Azure AD Domain Services.
$Vnet=New-AzVirtualNetwork `
  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
  -Location $AzureLocation `
  -Name $VnetName `
  -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 `
  -Subnet $AaddsSubnet,$WorkloadSubnet

$NSGName = "aaddsNSG"

# Create a rule to allow inbound TCP port 3389 traffic from Microsoft secure access workstations for troubleshooting
$nsg201 = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name AllowRD `
    -Access Allow `
    -Protocol Tcp `
    -Direction Inbound `
    -Priority 201 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix CorpNetSaw `
    -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange 3389

# Create a rule to allow TCP port 5986 traffic for PowerShell remote management
$nsg301 = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name AllowPSRemoting `
    -Access Allow `
    -Protocol Tcp `
    -Direction Inbound `
    -Priority 301 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix AzureActiveDirectoryDomainServices `
    -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange 5986

# Create the network security group and rules
$nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSGName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -Location $AzureLocation `
    -SecurityRules $nsg201,$nsg301

# Get the existing virtual network resource objects and information
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $VnetName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Name $SubnetName
$addressPrefix = $subnet.AddressPrefix

# Associate the network security group with the virtual network subnet
Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SubnetName `
    -VirtualNetwork $vnet `
    -AddressPrefix $addressPrefix `
    -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
$vnet | Set-AzVirtualNetwork

# Enable Azure AD Domain Services for the directory.
$replicaSetParams = @{
  Location = $AzureLocation
  SubnetId = "/subscriptions/$AzureSubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$VnetName/subnets/DomainServices"
}
$replicaSet = New-AzADDomainServiceReplicaSetObject @replicaSetParams

$domainServiceParams = @{
  Name = $ManagedDomainName
  ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroupName
  DomainName = $ManagedDomainName
  ReplicaSet = $replicaSet
}
New-AzADDomainService @domainServiceParams
```

Reference - [Enable Azure Active Directory Domain Services using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/powershell-create-instance)

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this before, let me try again and see if it works. Thanks!